# Localhost for Tornado

Tags: localhost, tornado

I'am trying to learn python cgi web programing and i couldn't handle all the apache configurations and i started to use tornado web server. 
- My question is where to put my .py file to run on a browser. I mean what is localhost[192.168.0.10] for tornado. 
And my OS is Macosx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting the file in your /Users//Sites/
Create a folder for your project and create a file named `__main__.py` with the tornado application.

You'll need to execute the script in your terminal.

```
cd ~/Sites/your_tornado_project
python ./
```

Your `__main__.py` file will be called and the tornado process will run.

---

Assuming you have apache configured properly.
To run from your browser you will need to do the following

1) Update your virtual hosts.

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
#
# Your virtual hosts file
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/you/Sites/your_project_dir"
    ServerName mysite.com
    ProxyPass              /                 http://localhost:4000/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse       /                 http://localhost:4000/ retry=0
    ErrorLog "/Users/you/Sites/your_project_dir/apache-error-log.log"
    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace the appropriate information with your tornado application.

2) Edit `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and add `127.0.0.1    mysite.com`

3) `sudo apachectl restart`

4) Open `mysite.com` in your browser. Tada!

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will ask you if i have any problem with that

Comment: Please do. I'd love to help. I'm currently working on projects related to your question. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot run the .py file on terminal it says:/__main__.py: line 1: print: command not found  -  Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add #!/usr/bim/env python line.

Comment: Anyway, __main__.py works on python for the first time. However, i cannot reach it through 127.0.0.1 and i tried 192.168.0.1/.../__main__.py it says: Forbidden

Comment: Sorry for this mass, finally make it work, Thanks for all your attention

Comment: You need to call `python` first. So, when your in the correct directory, execute `python ./` This will open your `__main__.py` file. Your doing this from your terminal to run your tornado framework.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Apache. You can just run the app:

```
python myapp.py
```

Then connect to it in a web browser:

```
http://localhost:8888
```

Where 8888 is the port that you called `application.listen` with.